# XMGrace: How to plot independent short lines with labels alongside my data curves?

Tags: plot, xmgrace

I need to plot some [potential energy curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy_surface). I.e. I need to be able to create graph looking like this:

[image]

Using the tutorial I'm able to recreate curves, create the legend etc. What I'm not able to do are the dissociation limits (labels on the right side of the picture in the red rectangle). Is there any way to make such "independent labels" at certain points on y-axis or do I have to create them like many little plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (albeit time-consuming) way is to use the "Window -> Drawing objects..." facilities and draw everything yourself by hand. Labels can be added with the "Text" button. Note that your life can be a made a bit easier by selecting "Position in: World coordinates" instead of "Viewport coordinates" and adding the real x and y value of each label.